# Script to find files with length longer than 80 characters

Tags: linux, windows, script

I have around 20 C++ files in my folder that I want to check for line length but I don't want to manually go through all of them. Is there any script/program in Linux/Windows that I can use to check an entire folder for files with long lines?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To check for files with lines long than 80 characters you can use grep:

`grep  -l '.\{80,\}'`

`-l` gives you only files with matches. If you want to recurse use `-R *` that could be applied to a specific subfolder like `src/*`

You can filter files by extension (or any other regex) using `--include='*.c'`

```
$ grep  -l '.\{80,\}' -R src/* --include='*.c'
src/main.c
src/model/model.c
```

If you want the exact lines you can remove `-l`. If you want line for matches add `-n`:

```
$ grep  -n '.\{80,\}' -R src/* --include='*.c'
src/main.vala:2: * A long line comment that takes more than 80 characters and needs some kind of fix.
src/model/model.c:14: * Another long line comment that takes more than 80 characters and needs some kind of fix.
```

if you have [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) available it is faster:

```
$ rg '.{80,}' src
src/main.c
2: * A long line comment that takes more than 80 characters and needs some kind of fix.

src/model/model.c
14: * Another long line comment that takes more than 80 characters and needs some kind of fix.
```

ripgrep accepts `--vimgrep` for a similar output than grep.

I strongly suggest to use `--color=auto` if not activated by default on your system.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this :

```
find -type f -exec bash -c '
    (( $(wc -l < "$1") > 80)) && echo "$1"
' -- {} \;
```

Comment: Doesn't this check the _number of lines_ rather than their length?